# Setting an Adapter to the ListView Android Studio

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to add some items in a ListView. When I swith the Layout (startActivity), I call the class Listing.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listing);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewLIST);
        String[] items = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"};
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_listing, R.id.listViewLIST, arrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I read some tutorials an followed every step but the app stops working always in the last line of code

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What am I missing?

Edit 27.12.2015 
The activity_listing.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="cigarkings.cigarking.Listing">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewLIST"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp" />

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listView" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_listing" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please post "activity_listing.xml"

Comment: also the logcat stacktrace of when it stops working would be helpful to see what's causing the app to stop

Comment: I added the activity_listing.xml .... the logcat stacktrace is too big to post it here ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming missing statement `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for your Coordinator Layout as a typographical error,the major error is in setting up array adapter.

In the statement : `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_listing, R.id.listViewLIST, arrayList);` the constructor parameters (2nd parameter:`R.layout.activity_listing` and 3rd parameter:`R.id.listViewLIST`) are incorrect.Array Adapter takes resource id of a textview as 3rd argument and not of a listview, and the layout resource id of the layout containing the textview is passed as 2nd argument.

So, one solution for this is to create a separate xml layout containing a textview and passing the layout resource id as 2nd argument and textview id as 3rd argument to the constructor of Array Adapter

Answer (score 0):

First of all activity listing should not be in this pattern.
If you are at beginning stage then First try this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/)...

The best explanation ever for beginners.
Then you have to implement custom listView using BaseAdaptor class and custom XML.